# Prove $f$ is injective if and only if $g$ is surjiective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

**Problem:** Give mapping $f,g: X \to X$ and $f \circ g$ is bijective. Prove that
$$f \text{ is injective} \iff g \text{ is surjective}.$$
**My attempt:**

($\Leftarrow$)Give $y,y' \in X$ satisfy $f(y)=f(y')$. Since $g$ is surjective then exists $x,x' \in X$ that $y=g(x),y=g(x')$. This yields
$$f[g(x)]=f[g(x')].$$
Thus, $f\circ g(x)=f\circ g(x')$. And then, we have $x=x'$ since $f\circ g$ is bijiective. Therefore, $g(x)=g(x')$ or $y=y'$.

So, $f$ is injective.

($\Rightarrow$) I am stucking here now.

Loof forward to your support. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f\circ g$ is bijective implies that $f$ is onto and $g$ is one-one.

Given $f$ is one-one, so $f$ is a bijection, so is $f^{-1}$.

So $f^{-1}\circ(f\circ g)=(f^{-1}\circ f)\circ g=g$ is a composition of bijections and hence a bijection, i.e. $g$ is onto.

You can use similar reasoning for reverse implication.

Answer (score 1):

Write $h:=f\circ g$ and $h^{-1}$ for its inverse.

Assume $f$ is injective. Let $y\in X$ be given. Then $$f(g(h^{-1}(f(y))))=h(h^{-1}(f(y))= f(y)$$
so that by injectivity of $f$,
$$ g(h^{-1}(f(y))) = y,$$
which shows that $y=g(x)$ for $x=h^{-1}(f(y))$.